# Where on Pacer.gov should I look for affidavits authored by a certain expert?

Tags: legal-research, pacer

I've heard that it is possible to search pacer.gov to find all affidavits authored by a specific expert.  But I cannot find that function on the? I did not find anything on this in this training manual: https://www.pacer.gov/documents/pacermanual.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run the [RECAP](https://free.law/recap/) project at Free Law Project, and spend a ton of my time in the guts of PACER and CM/ECF.

I don't think it's possible to do what you're asking. The only idea I have is [searching repositories like ours](https://www.courtlistener.com/recap/), where you can do full text search for an expert's name.

Wish there was an easier way, but PACER is...not the best system.

Comment: FYI, the Free Law Project looks very interesting; I'm taking a look.